# Average Aggregation Queries in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

Ok, still in my toy app, I want to find out the average mileage on a group of car owners' odometers. This is pretty easy on the client but doesn't scale. Right? But on the server, I don't exactly see how to accomplish it.

Questions:

1. How do you implement something on the server then use it on the client?
2. How do you use the $avg aggregation function of mongo to leverage its optimized aggregation function?
3. Or alternatively to (2) how do you do a map/reduce on the server and make it available to the client?

The suggestion by @HubertOG was to use Meteor.call, which makes sense and I did this:

```
# Client side
Template.mileage.average_miles = ->
  answer = null
  Meteor.call "average_mileage", (error, result) ->
    console.log "got average mileage result #{result}"
    answer = result
  console.log "but wait, answer = #{answer}"
  answer

# Server side
Meteor.methods average_mileage: ->
  console.log "server mileage called"
  total = count = 0
  r = Mileage.find({}).forEach (mileage) ->
    total += mileage.mileage
    count += 1
  console.log "server about to return #{total / count}"
  total / count
```

That would seem to work fine, but it doesn't because as near as I can tell `Meteor.call` is an asynchronous call and `answer` will always be a null return. Handling stuff on the server seems like a common enough use case that I must have just overlooked something. What would that be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As of Meteor 0.6.5, the collection API doesn't support aggregation queries yet because there's no (straightforward) way to do live updates on them. However, you can still write them yourself, and make them available in a `Meteor.publish`, although the result will be static. In my opinion, doing it this way is still preferable because you can merge multiple aggregations and use the client-side collection API.

```js
Meteor.publish("someAggregation", function (args) {
    var sub = this;
    // This works for Meteor 0.6.5
    var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;

    // Your arguments to Mongo's aggregation. Make these however you want.
    var pipeline = [
        { $match: doSomethingWith(args) },
        { $group: {
            _id: whatWeAreGroupingWith(args),
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }}
    ];

    db.collection("server_collection_name").aggregate(        
        pipeline,
        // Need to wrap the callback so it gets called in a Fiber.
        Meteor.bindEnvironment(
            function(err, result) {
                // Add each of the results to the subscription.
                _.each(result, function(e) {
                    // Generate a random disposable id for aggregated documents
                    sub.added("client_collection_name", Random.id(), {
                        key: e._id.somethingOfInterest,                        
                        count: e.count
                    });
                });
                sub.ready();
            },
            function(error) {
                Meteor._debug( "Error doing aggregation: " + error);
            }
        )
    );
});
```

The above is an example grouping/count aggregation. Some things of note:

- When you do this, you'll naturally be doing an aggregation on `server_collection_name` and pushing the results to a different collection called `client_collection_name`.
- This subscription isn't going to be live, and will probably be updated whenever the arguments change, so we use a really simple loop that just pushes all the results out.
- The results of the aggregation don't have Mongo ObjectIDs, so we generate some arbitrary ones of our own.
- The callback to the aggregation needs to be wrapped in a Fiber. I use `Meteor.bindEnvironment` here but one can also use a `Future` for more low-level control.

If you start combining the results of publications like these, you'll need to carefully consider how the randomly generated ids impact the merge box. However, a straightforward implementation of this is just a standard database query, except it is more convenient to use with Meteor APIs client-side.

**TL;DR version**: Almost anytime you are pushing data out from the server, a `publish` is preferable to a `method`.

For more information about different ways to do aggregation, **[check out this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/RH_WEIp2uDs/39eeszSu2wMJ)**.

Comment: I don't want to leave this answer without a "thank you." It's a totally awesome answer. I got pulled away on another project temporarily, but Andrew, you obviously put a lot of thought into this and I'm very appreciative.

Comment: @SteveRoss you're welcome. Thanks for the kind words!

Comment: Kudos for the excellent aggregation example.  It was the only one that worked for me.  And that you managed to do it without a package, with MongoInternals, and in a publish function... icing on red velvet cake.  Thank you for sharing!

Comment: Great answer Andrew. Do you know of any packages that abstract the tricky parts out here?

Comment: @TomColeman https://github.com/jhoxray/meteor-mongo-extensions but it's not maintained.

Comment: Is there any way to get the subscription live/reactive?

Comment: @while Not easily. It's tough, which is why it hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: Is this seriously the easiest way to do aggregations with Meteor?  I need to query for matches using $in so the package mentioned above won't help because it only does other methods.

Comment: @JohnAllen you're not just doing a database aggregation here, you're also sending it to the client. It's hard to do a live aggregation result, hence it hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: Awesome, well thanks for posting this answer regardless!

Comment: @AndrewMao I'm struggling to understand the client/server collection part of this.  Are there two collections for ease of querying, or is this required?  For my purposes, I'm attempting to sort results by number of `$in` match results so I'm not sure this is what I need.  Is the above the easiest and correct way to do this?  Sure wish there was some more examples or documentation for this.  Have read through all of the Meteor group threads, I believe.

Comment: If you didn't pick up on it, I just want to subscribe to a normal query here for one time calls - I just need the query sorted by number of matches.

Comment: Is it possible to return a cursor (mongodb 2.6+) instead of the results so that it works the Meteor way as if doing a find() or do we still need to handle it using pub.added(), pub.ready(), etc? http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/collection.html#aggregate

Comment: @rclai89 Meteor cursors do live data updates with diffs, which seems like it's going to be nearly impossible for aggregations. Even if Mongo is returning a cursor, we're nowhere near getting live data cursors for aggregations yet.

Answer (score 2):

I did this with the 'aggregate' method. (ver 0.7.x)

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
Meteor.methods({
    'aggregate' : function(param){
        var fut = new Future();
        MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo._getCollection(param.collection).aggregate(param.pipe,function(err, result){
            fut.return(result);
        });
        return fut.wait();
    }
    ,'test':function(param){
        var _param = {
            pipe : [
            { $unwind:'$data' },
            { $match:{ 
                'data.y':"2031",
                'data.m':'01',
                'data.d':'01'
            }},
            { $project : {
                '_id':0
                ,'project_id'               : "$project_id"
                ,'idx'                      : "$data.idx"
                ,'y'                        : '$data.y'
                ,'m'                        : '$data.m'
                ,'d'                        : '$data.d'
            }}
        ],
            collection:"yourCollection"
        }
        Meteor.call('aggregate',_param);
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Meteor.methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods) for that.

```
// server
Meteor.methods({
  average: function() {
    ...
    return something;
  },

});

// client

var _avg = {                      /* Create an object to store value and dependency */
  dep: new Deps.Dependency();
};

Template.mileage.rendered = function() {
  _avg.init = true;
};

Template.mileage.averageMiles = function() {
  _avg.dep.depend();              /* Make the function rerun when _avg.dep is touched */
  if(_avg.init) {                 /* Fetch the value from the server if not yet done */
    _avg.init = false; 
    Meteor.call('average', function(error, result) {
      _avg.val = result;
      _avg.dep.changed();         /* Rerun the helper */
    });
  }
  return _avg.val;
});
```

Comment: So I'm happily going along getting new input values and so on. At what point is there a write-through to the server. Cuz what I'm seeing is that this would work except that the data on the client has not yet made it to the server.

Comment: I've amended the original question.

Comment: You can use dependencies to create reactivity where needed. I've updated my answer. The result may be a bit overcomplicated, at this moment I'm not sure how to do it simpler in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want reactivity, use `Meteor.publish` instead of `Meteor.call`. There's an example in the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) where they publish the number of messages in a given room (just above the documentation for `this.userId`), you should be able to do something similar.

Comment: So, reactivity seems good because whenever someone updates their mileage the average changes. So that would recommend publish/subscribe according to what you say. But it seems to me that pub/sub is more for returning filtered or mapped collections than scalar values like an average. This seems like it should only be a line or two of code -- wouldn't you think?

Comment: @SteveRoss I agree that a common feature like this should be easy to write, but Meteor has no special support for it (yet, version 6.5), so the alternatives are using methods/call or publish/subscribe. Given the similar example in the docs, and the benefit of reactivity, I would go with publish/subscribe.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with publishing a collection containing just a single document with your scalar value.

And who knows?  Maybe one day you'll want more than one average... and then you can publish multiple documents :)