# How to merge and sort arrays from the results of Collection.find({}) in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I have such Collection structure

```js
{
    "_id" : "12ds5dsfSSFS2sfds",
    "name": "Peter Jackson",
    "films" : [
        {
            "name" : "King Kong",
            "date" : "2005"
        },
        {
            "name" : "The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey",
            "date" : "2012"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "HHdfdsBfSSFS2sfds",
    "name": "Martin Scorsese",
    "films" : [
        {
            "name" : "Goodfellas",
            "date" : "1990"
        },
        {
            "name" : "The Wolf of Wall Street",
            "date" : "2013"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I need is to have sorted list like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/K7VGy/embedded/result/

### [image: Sorted list as a result]

So, **the question is** - is it possible to merge all fields from `films` arrays, then sort them, based on `date` and then pass to template?

Maybe I have chosen the wrong collection structure, and it could be improved somehow?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For mine I would do this server side with the use of the aggregate method, and doing this server side you need to do some digging to get at the aggregate method:

```js
var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;

db.collection("server_collection_name").aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$films" },
    { "$sort": { "films.date": -1 } },
],
function(err,result) {

    // do work in here   
});
```

Which will essentially return data already formatted and ordered like so:

```js
{
    "_id" : "HHdfdsBfSSFS2sfds",
    "name" : "Martin Scorsese",
    "films" : {
            "name" : "The Wolf of Wall Street",
            "date" : "2013"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "12ds5dsfSSFS2sfds",
    "name" : "Peter Jackson",
    "films" : {
            "name" : "The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey",
            "date" : "2012"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "12ds5dsfSSFS2sfds",
    "name" : "Peter Jackson",
    "films" : {
            "name" : "King Kong",
            "date" : "2005"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "HHdfdsBfSSFS2sfds",
    "name" : "Martin Scorsese",
    "films" : {
            "name" : "Goodfellas",
            "date" : "1990"
    }
}
```

Then you can do really cool things with that on the server such as change the filtering, or the sort order and paginate results.

So I think this is the better way than manipulating a structure like above on the client, in which you could not possibly sort and then paginate.

That would be the better way and you can make use of Meteor's `publish` in order make this look more integral, or just use meteor methods. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18884223/2313887) and another [external discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meteor-talk/RH_WEIp2uDs/39eeszSu2wMJ) for more information on aggregation with meteor.

Also see the aggregation framework [operator reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) for further information on how to customize.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I have one more question though - is it possible to make the aggregation reactive?

Answer (score 1):

How about using underscore for merging:

```
var merged = _.extend({}, first_obj, second_obj);
```

For sorting we can also use underscore:

```
var sorted = _.sortBy(merged, function(item) {
    return new Date(item.films.date)*(-1); // to convert it to negative number
}
```

Then use newly created **sorted** variable in a template helper to output this.