# Aggregate in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I need to make a query using aggregate in the MongoDB, but as the meteor does not support'm trying to use the extension server-aggregation.
I'm using the code on the server like this:

```
var result = aggregates('publicadores',[{$match: {_id : _id}},{ $unwind: '$relatorios' },{ $sort: {'relatorios.mes': -1 }}]);
```

The consultation is being done correctly, but when passing data by Publish Meteor is returning the following error:

```
Exception from sub MvPSGj5bf2jHFsRng Error: Publish function returned an array of non-Cursors
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error, or some other way to apply the aggregate in Meteor?

Comment: What MongoDB version are you using, there was a change recently that meant the output of aggregate has changed, it seems the error is moaning about that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Average Aggregation Queries in Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520567/average-aggregation-queries-in-meteor)

Comment: I'm using version 2.4.9 of MongoDB, but the aggregate command works, the error happens when the meteor tries to pass the result by PubSub

Comment: It seems that it will take so that I can make the aggregate function in Meteor. But I managed to solve my problem in another way. Did the normal query in mongo using Meteor and the client created a helper for grouping and sorting. Do not know if it's the best way, but're working. Thanks guys

Comment: @MuriloVenturoso can you share work around

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate packages for MongoDB