# Meteor Group Collection by Field and their sum

Tags: meteor, aggregate

I've been searching for answer to this question but sadly I don't see that will answer my question.  I have an expense collection that looks like this

```
 { subcategory: 'Category-1', amount: 320 },
 { subcategory: 'Category-2', amount: 148 },
 { subcategory: 'Category-1', amount: 500 },
 { subcategory: 'Category-3', amount: 672 },
 { subcategory: 'Category-3', amount: 196 },
 { subcategory: 'Category-1', amount: 298 },
... etc
```

and I wanted to show in my summary report through my table like this

```
     **Category Name**         **Amount**

     1. Category-1                 1118      
     2. Category-2                 148
     3. Category-3                 868
```

which I am then going to render these data on my table template

```
{{#each expensesentries}}
  <tr>
     <td>{{category}}</td>
     <td>{{formatAmount amount}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}} `
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take care, that your approved solution requires that all data is stored on the client. What does it mean?

If you have a collection with about 1000 or even more entries than you have to publish all these entries and store these entries on the client before you can do a group. That requires a lot of space and costs  lot of performance. So if your collection must not be reactive than you should look for a server side group via aggregation. Check this stackoverflow-post:

[Aggregation via meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18884223/1345989)

**EDIT:**
Basically the linked article shows everything you need. I hope you are already common with publish and subscribe?

```
Meteor.publish("expensesentries", function (args) {
    var sub = this;
    var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;

    var pipeline = [
        { $group: {
            _id: subcategory,
            count: { $sum: amount }
        }}
    ];

    db.collection("server_collection_name").aggregate(        
        pipeline,

        Meteor.bindEnvironment(
            function(err, result) {
                _.each(result, function(e) {
                  sub.added("client_collection_name", Random.id(), {
                    category: item._id,
                    amount: item.count
                  });
                });
                sub.ready();
            },
            function(error) {
                Meteor._debug( "Error doing aggregation: " + error);
            }
        )
    );
});
```

[Check mongodb aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

If you use iron router than you should subscribe in there.

```
  waitOn: function () {
    return [Meteor.subscribe('expensesentries')];
  },
```

In your Template:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  expensesentries: function() {
    return client_collection_name.find();
  }
});
```

This query could also be definded in your iron-router data callback.
Dont expect this to work out of the box. Read manuals of iron-router, mongodb aggregation and try to understand whats going on. Happy coding :)

Comment: I have seen the link you provided before I posted my question here. The problem is I am still new to programming and can't figure out how to make it work with my needs. Can you answer my question using that method they way @David Weldon does?

Comment: Check my update. I cant deliver you a full example but maybe this is a good entry point for you.

Comment: okay. it's clearer to me now. =) let my try integrate this to my code.

Comment: still not working.`var sub = this;
    var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;
    var pipeline = [
        { $group: {
            _id: "$subcat",
            totalamount: {$sum: "$amount"}
        }},
    ];
  
    db.collection("gifts").aggregate(
      pipeline,
      Meteor.bindEnvironment(
        function(err,result) {
          _.each(result, function(e) {
            sub.added("Gifts", Random.id(), {
              subcat: e._id,
              amount: e.totalamount
            });
          });
          sub.ready();
        },`

Comment: Does your aggregate function returns a dataset?

Comment: this is what it shows when i do web console Gifts.find(): `LocalCollection.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: null, _selectorId: undefined, matcher: Minimongo.Matcher, skip: undefined…}` and if I I do Gifts.find().fetch().. it just show `[]`

Comment: Make a console.log(result) in your serverside aggregate function to debug if you query returns something.

Comment: console.log(result) actually gives the result.. this is my whole code for this matter [linl] (http://pastebin.com/Q7tV7gq9).. but in the client side I don't know why its not showing the same

Comment: Cant find a fault. Nice idea to push a paste. I put in a paste for you of my working code. I didnt short it up (no time) but this code is working for me. Maybe you can find what is missing. http://pastebin.com/qTy8rVW8

Comment: got it working.. i forgot to define a new collection to pass on after the aggregation results.

Comment: Yeah good job, but dont forget it is not reactive for now but maybe in future.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but give this a try:

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  expensesentries: function() {
    var subs = {};
    Expenses.find().forEach(function(e) {
      if (subs[e.subcategory] == null)
        subs[e.subcategory] = 0;
      subs[e.subcategory] += e.amount;
    });

    var results = [];
    _.each(subs, function(value, key) {
      results.push({category: key, amount: value});
    });

    return results;
  }
});
```

The first part aggregates the amounts by category into a single object. So `subs` will look like:

```
{ 'Category-1': 1118, 'Category-2': 148, 'Category-3': 868 }
```

The second part builds an array (`results`) with the necessary key-value pairs for your template. When done, it should look like:

```
[ { category: 'Category-1', amount: 1118 },
  { category: 'Category-2', amount: 148 },
  { category: 'Category-3', amount: 868 } ]
```

Comment: can this be run on server during publish or on meteor.call command?

Comment: Yes, that's recommended if you have a lot of data and you only need the aggregated version on the client. The easiest way is to turn it into a method - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147813/how-to-use-meteor-methods-inside-of-a-template-helper) for more details.