# Meteor collection how to get last 4 elements #Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, collections, meteor

How to get last 4 elements from meteor collection?
For example. 
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');

I like to get last 4 posts from "Posts" collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have the date on the Posts items. You can do the following to get the "last post" or top 4 most recent:

> Posts.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 4});

or if you mean the last or oldest Posts

> Posts.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: 1}, limit: 4});

Comment: ralphie thank you! How can I get these posts one by one? For example if it was array i can get posts[post.length-1] is the last one,

Comment: please check my previous question asked here if it helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729768/meteor-group-collection-by-field-and-their-sum/24730073?noredirect=1#comment38424845_24730073