# Meteor: Get count of collection by name. Accessing global scope on server

Tags: meteor

I'd like to create a method that returns the count of a generic collection.

Calling the method would look something like this:

```
Meteor.call('getCollectionCount', 'COLLECTION_NAME');
```

And the result would be the collection count.

The server method code would look something like this:

```
getCollectionCount: function (collectionName) {
    return window[collectionName].find().count();
}
```

This won't work because window isn't defined on the server, but is something similar possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `global` instead of `window`.

Note that this uses the variable name assigned to the collection object, not the name given to the collection. For this to work with `Meteor.users` you need to assign another variable name.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  users = Meteor.users;
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.call('count', 'users', function (err, res) {
    // do something with number of users
  });
}
```

Also probably a good idea to check that `global[collectionName]` is actually a collection.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this code which makes the following assumptions :

- collections are declared in the global scope as top level objects.
- collections are searched by collection name, not the collection variable identifier.

So client code should declare their collections like this :

```
MyCollection=new Meteor.Collection("my-collection");
```

And use the function like this :

```
var clientResult=Meteor.call("getCollectionCount","my-collection",function(error,result){
  if(error){
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }
  console.log("actual server-side count is : ",result);
});
console.log("published subset count is : ",clientResult);
```

The method supports execution on the client (this is known as method stub or method simulation) but will only yield the count of the collection subset replicated client-side, to get the real count wait for server-side response using a callback.

```
/packages/my-package/lib/my-package.js

getCollection=function(collectionName){
  if(collectionName=="users"){
    return Meteor.users;
  }
  var globalScope=Meteor.isClient?window:global;
  for(var property in globalScope){
    var object=globalScope[property];
    if(object instanceof Meteor.Collection && object._name==collectionName){
      return object;
    }
  }
  throw Meteor.Error(500,"No collection named "+collectionName);
};

Meteor.methods({
  getCollectionCount:function(collectionName){
    return getCollection(collectionName).find().count();
  }
});
```

As Meteor.users is not declared as a top level variable you have to account for the special case (yes, this is ugly).

Digging into Meteor's collection handling code could provide a better alternative (getting access to a collection handle by collection name).

Final words on this : using a method call to count a collection documents is unfortunately non-reactive, so given the Meteor paradigm this might be of little use.

Most of the time you will want to fetch the number of documents in a collection for pagination purpose (something like a "Load more" button in a posts list for example), and as the rest of the Meteor architecture you'll want this to be reactive.

To count documents in a collection reactively you'll have to setup a slightly more complicated publication as showcased in the "counts-by-room" example in the docs.

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish

This is something you definitely want to read and understand.

This smart package is actually doing it right :

http://atmospherejs.com/package/publish-counts

It provides a helper function that is publishing the counts of any cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the collections on some other property that the server has access too.  You could even call it `window` if you really wanted to.

```
var wow = new Meteor.Collection("wow");
collections["wow"] = wow;

getCollectionCount: function (collectionName) {
    return collections[collectionName].find().count();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So the motivation behind my question is being able to make a package that does this. Users should be able to use the package even if they haven't set up their application as you've described.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the package users to change how they work with collections in the app then I think you should use MongoInternals to get collections by name from the db.  Not tested but here is an example:

```
//on server
Meteor.methods({
  count: function( name ){
    var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;
    var collection = db.collection( name );
    return collection && collection.count({});
  }
});
```

Another [example of MongoInternals use is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520567/average-aggregation-queries-in-meteor).  Documentation of the count() function available from the [mongo driver is here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/).