# Set fixed order to document mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

I have these four documents:

```
    {
        "_id" : "qbz2nyPccFzYjYmWo",
        "position" : 0,
        "part_order" : 30
    },
    {
        "_id" : "qbz2nyPccFzYjYmWo",
        "position" : 1,
        "part_order" : 34
    },
    {
        "_id" : "EaCSGEKmqfrgFFXBs",
        "position" : 2
    },
    {
        "_id" : "N3Z6NnWhN35dX4MLq",
        "position" : 3,
        "part_order" : 31
    }
```

I want to order the collection. I tried with:

```
db.queue.find().sort({part_order:1,position:1})
```

But it separates the documents with part_order of without part_order.
How Can I fix documents in the positions and just order the documents with part_order in a mongo query?

The output has to be:

```
    {
        "_id" : "qbz2nyPccFzYjYmWo",
        "position" : 0,
        "part_order" : 30
    },
    {
        "_id" : "N3Z6NnWhN35dX4MLq",
        "position" : 3,
        "part_order" : 31
    },
    {
        "_id" : "EaCSGEKmqfrgFFXBs",
        "position" : 2
    },
    {
        "_id" : "qbz2nyPccFzYjYmWo",
        "position" : 1,
        "part_order" : 34
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to sort like this db.queue.find().sort({position:1, part_order:1})

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "fix documents in the positions and just order the documents with part_order"? You want to sort documents according to the position and for those with the same position use the part_order?

Comment: @joao if you do for example db.queue.find().sort({position:1, part_order:-1}) the order is not that we wish because it is just ordered by position. Thank you

Comment: I want to order all documents with part_order but the documents which has not part_order attribute has to have the position set in position attribute like they are fixed. Like they are no moving.

Comment: @kahonmlg can you post your expected output

Comment: @yogesh I have added the output now.

Comment: @joao I hope you understand the question well with this new example. Thanks

Comment: @JohnnyHK I know, that is why I have the attribute position.

Comment: @kahonmlg Oh, I get it now. Thanks for clarifying. You may be best off just sorting by `part_order` and then performing the `position` sort override in your own code.

Comment: @JohnnyHK this is not good for me because I use meteor and the reactive property of collections just works with cursors. If I manipulate the output to an array I lose the reactive property of collection.

Comment: You will have to code this, much as suggested. There is a detailed example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18884223/2313887) and though the question is about aggregation, the real answer is about using [`.publish()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-publish)

Comment: I have publish two collections. One with no part_order, another one with part order. I publish both and I process that in client. It is the best way I can do from now. Thanks.