# How to filter MongoDB records by date and time?

Tags: mongodb, date, meteor

I'm learning how to use MeteorJS and I have a record that looks like:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.meals.find()
{ "_id" : "kHjRCXRRoC6JLYjJY", "name" : "Spaghetti & Meatballs", "calories" : "300", "eatenAt" : ISODate("2015-05-20T07:07:00Z"), "userId" : "movpJRhRMwyMZDBqf", "author" : "sergiotapia" }
{ "_id" : "vcQZ2S4MXHs49BknJ", "name" : "Lasgagna", "calories" : "150", "eatenAt" : ISODate("2015-05-20T07:07:00Z"), "userId" : "movpJRhRMwyMZDBqf", "author" : "sergiotapia" }
{ "_id" : "oqw4HZ5tybBKfMJmj", "name" : "test", "calories" : "900", "eatenAt" : ISODate("2015-05-20T07:38:00Z"), "userId" : "movpJRhRMwyMZDBqf", "author" : "sergiotapia" }
{ "_id" : "Pq6vawvTnXQniBvMZ", "name" : "booya", "calories" : "1000", "eatenAt" : ISODate("2015-05-19T07:37:00Z"), "userId" : "movpJRhRMwyMZDBqf", "author" : "sergiotapia" }
```

I want to filter these records using the ISODate value by both date and time. For example, get me the records from January 1st to January 12nd that are between 9am and 2pm.

Is it possible using a single field, or do I need to have a separate field specifically for time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is basically:

find documents that are between 2015-01-01 AND 2015-01-12 AND have time between 09:00 AND 14:00.

One approach is using the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** in particular the **[Date Aggregation Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/)**. You can use the **[meteorhacks:aggregate](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate)** package that adds proper aggregation support for Meteor. This package exposes `.aggregate` method on `Mongo.Collection` instances.

Add to your app with

```
meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate
```

Then simply use `.aggregate` function like below.

```
var meals = new Mongo.Collection('meals');
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$project": {
            "year": { "$year": "$eatenAt" },
            "month": { "$month": "$eatenAt" },
            "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$eatenAt" },
            "hour": { "$hour": "$eatenAt" },        
            "name" : 1,
            "calories" : 1,
            "eatenAt" : 1,
            "userId" : 1,
            "author" : 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "year": 2015,
            "month": 1,
            "day": { "$gte": 1, "$lte": 12 },
            "hour": { "$gt": 8, "$lt": 14 }
        }
    }
];

var result = meals.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: Where do I need to place this code? I read it's server only but I don't know where it's supposed to do

Comment: If it's server side then just call `db.meals.aggregate(pipeline)` where `pipeline` is the above variable that contains the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: One little question, once I call this server-side method and get the right data, how can I apply it to the template it's currently running on?

Comment: @Serg Now that's where you can use the code above within your template function, making sure you add the package to your app by `meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate`. I can't get into detail as the context is quite broad but that's the general concept above. Refer to this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18884223/122005) for more detail.