# MongoDB Aggregate & Grouping Issue in MeteorJS

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Using MongoDB in Meteor JS, how do you use Meteor Aggregate properly?

The intended result is to return grouped users by their userId and sum up a boolean field called "progressState" (true/false).

For example the document can have:

```
user 001 - true
user 001 - false
user 001 - true
user 003 - false
user 005 - true
```

but the intended result would be:

```
user 001: 2 true
user 003: 0 true
user 005: 1 true
etc..
```

My attempt gives the following error:

```
"exception: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'."
```

Here is my Meteor Code:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('completedLB', {
    find: function() {
        return userCompleted.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    "progressState": "true"
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    "_id": "$userId",
                    "count": {
                        "$sum": "$progressState"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $sort : {
                    "$progressState": -1
                }
            }
        ]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the [meteor hacks aggregate](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/) package to implement an `.aggregate()` command on your collection, then it will only just return an array in response. So you need to work that into a form of a published collection:

```js
Meteor.publish("completedLB,function() {
    var self = this;

    var results = userCompleted.aggregate([
        { "$match": { "progressState": true } },
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$userId",
             "progressState": { "$first": "$progressState" },
             "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},
        { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
    ]);

    _.each(results,function(result) {
        self.added("client_collection_name",Random.id(), {
            userId: result._id,
            progressState: result.progressState,
            count: result.count
        });
    });
    self.ready();
});
```

Or to include the `false` counts as your suggested output suggests itself:

```js
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$userId",
             "progressState": { "$first": true },
             "count": { "$sum": { "$cond": ["$progressState", 1,0] }
        }},
        { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
```

As the pipeline with a [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) evaluation to convert to numeric.

Where in the basic aggregation you are just "totalling" the matched results and of course the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) refers to a field present in the output, which by your example would be the "userId" value now in the `_id` key from aggregation, but could also be "count" to order by the total count if wanted.

That part was producing the error, as `$sort` is a present field and not a field value with `$` notation.

But of course to publish as a client accessible collection you need to replace the actual `_id` with something expected. So random id generation works here, as does the inclusion of the other fields.

For a bit more detail, and also an alternate to the "hacks" package that just works with a vanilla installation, there is also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31603477/5031275)by myself that has a complete listing as an example.

Comment: console.log(results) gives me the sum, but in templates, I still get the individual values, uncomputed.

Comment: See question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393216/meteor-aggregated-result-not-showing-in-template