# Meteor Aggregated result not showing in template

Tags: meteor

I am following this [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31824044/1757321). In console, I get the correct aggregated sum.

```
Meteor.publish('hoursTotal', function() {
    var self = this;
    var pipeline = [
        {$group: {_id: "$userId", hours: {$sum: "$hours" }}}
    ];
    var result = Reports.aggregate(pipeline);

    _.each(result, function(result) {
        self.added("hoursTotalSum", result._id, {
            userId: result._id,
            hours: result.hours
        });
    });
    console.log(result);
    self.ready();
});
```

I've subscribed to the new collection created in client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('hoursTotalSum');
```

My template helper:

```
Template.statsBrief.helpers({
    hoursTotalSum: function() {
        var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
        return Reports.find({userId: currentUserId});
    },
});
```

My template:

```
{{#each hoursTotalSum}} {{hours}} {{/each}}
```

Meteor console retunrs this:

```
[ { _id: 'F8ZEWeKMoRfXaEGNa', hours: 30 },
I20151221-09:57:09.097(0)?   { _id: 'ufALZHfhWyQ8pMkgD', hours: 85 } ]
```

Meteor templates return this:

```
50 20 15
```

Although the summation is happening right, and the backend console confirms that, I'm struggling to get the value into the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully use aggregates via the [meteorhacks:aggregate](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate) package however I do it a bit differently from your example. Rather than debug your code I will show how I would achieve the same goal.

*Note* :The code below is in coffeescript

**Write a Meteor Method**

Create a server side Meteor Method to perform the aggregation. You do not need to `publish` your aggregation as all the processing happens on the server and the results are under your control via the `$project` step.

```
Meteor.methods 
    getHoursTotal: ->
        return null unless @userId
        check @userId, String
        pipeline = [
            {$group:{'_id': @userId, 'hours':{$sum:'$hours'}}},
            {$project: 
                _id:false, 
                userId:'$_id', 
                hours: '$hours', 
            }
        ]
        return reports.aggregate pipeline
```

In your code you were processing each item in the result. It looked like you were just wanting rename `_id` to `userId` and include the calculated `hours`  field. I did this in the `$project` step instead.

**Call the Meteor Method**

Your code depends on the `userId` being available, so we only want to run it after the user has signed in. We can make this reactive using `tracker`.

```
Tracker.autorun ->
    return unless Meteor.userId()?
    Meteor.call 'getHoursTotal', (err, res) ->
        Session.set 'hoursTotal', res
```

Now the code will only tun if the `Meteor.userId` is not null and when it does run the `hoursTotal` will be stored in the `Session` ready for use.

**Expose the Results**

To expose the results nicely it is a good idea to put it on a Template helper.

```
Template.statsBrief.helpers
    hoursTotal: -> Session.get 'hoursTotal'
```

I think performing the aggregate and exposing the results in this way is simpler whilst also benefiting from being fully reactive.

Comment: Your solution is working pretty well, reative et all, but I don't seem to still access in templates. I am able to `Session.get('hoursTotal')` in console in client, but in the templates, I'm struggling

Comment: Okay, figured it out. the `res` object contains an index of `0`, thus I simply did `Session.set('hoursTotal', res[0]);` This your approach is more reactive and interesting. Although I could get the other approach to also work, I think I prefer this than the former