# How can i calculate price positive and negative price using mongodb or robomongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, robo3t

below is my userpricing collection data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584bc9ba420a6b189c510af6"),
    "user_id" : 1,
    "mobilenumber":"01234",
    "price" : 2000.0,
    "type" : "credit",

},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584bc9ba420a6b189c510af6"),
    "user_id" : 1,
    "mobilenumber":"01234",
    "price" : -1000.0,
    "type" : "credit",

},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584bc9ba420a6b189c3323w23"),
    "user_id" : 2,
    "mobilenumber":"04321",
    "price" : 1000.0,
    "type" : "credit",

}
```

here i want to calculate total postive and total negative price  of all user and i need to check whether that user is exists or not in summary collection.if record not exists we need to create document  in summary collection if its exists we need to update  "Totalpositiveprice","Totalnegativeprice" and "Balanceprice"

in summary table already exists this record

```
    {

        "user_id": "1",
        "mobilenumber":"01234",
        "Totalpositiveprice": 3000.0,
        "Totalnegativeprice": 0,
        "Balanceprice": 3000.0
    },
   {

        "user_id": "3",
        "mobilenumber":"05555",
        "Totalpositiveprice": 1000.0,
        "Totalnegativeprice": -100,
        "Balanceprice": 900.0
    }
```

1. we need to update the document for "mobilenumber":"01234",
2. we need to create new document for "mobilenumber":"04321",
3. "mobilenumber":"05555" no need to do anything bcoz nothing is there in userpricing

finally i should get  summary collection like this

```
 {

        "user_id": "1",
        "mobilenumber":"01234"
        "Totalpositiveprice": 5000.0,
        "Totalnegativeprice": -1000.0,
        "Balanceprice": 4000.0
    },
    {

        "user_id": "2",
         "mobilenumber":"04321"
        "Totalpositiveprice": 1000.0,
        "Totalnegativeprice": 0,
        "Balanceprice": 1000.0
    },
    {

    "user_id": "3",
    "mobilenumber":"05555",
    "Totalpositiveprice": 1000.0,
    "Totalnegativeprice": -100,
    "Balanceprice": 900.0
}
```

Comment: If Balance means sum all prices from 1 user, than you have an answer below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional $sum in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102596/conditional-sum-in-mongodb)

Comment: about similar but he/she also wanted to export into another collection

Comment: @ShaishabRoy the reason OP  is asking is because he doesn't know how to do the conditional sum not how  to export the result to a new collection.

Comment: agree with you @Styvane

Comment: You have to remove the `$out` stage from your aggregation. After you get the results from aggregation use bulk write API from your driver  to insert/update into your `summary` collection.

Comment: can you give me the code so that i will check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try bulk write to bulk upload the update queries created from aggregation result and update the `summary` collection.

Here is a quick code that you can try from Mongo shell and you can adjust to your needs.

The below code queries for `user_id` and increments the price values based on the aggregation values and upserts if no matching user_id is found.

You should change the `batch` based on your needs.

```
var bulk = db.getCollection('summary').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
var batch = 1;

db.getCollection('userpricing').aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id:"$user_id", 
        Totalpositiveprice:{$sum:{$cond:[{ '$gt': ['$price', 0]}, "$price", 0]}}, 
        Totalnegativeprice:{$sum:{$cond:[{ '$lt': ['$price', 0]}, "$price", 0]}},
        Balanceprice:{"$sum":"$price"}}
     },
    {$project: {_id:0, user_id:"$_id", Totalpositiveprice:1, Totalnegativeprice:1, Balanceprice:1}}
]).forEach(function(doc){ 
    var user_id = doc.user_id; 
    var totalpositiveprice = doc.Totalpositiveprice; 
    var totalnegativeprice = doc.Totalnegativeprice; 
    var balanceprice = doc.Balanceprice; 
    bulk.find({ "user_id" : user_id }).upsert().updateOne(
      { $inc: {"Totalpositiveprice" : totalpositiveprice, "Totalnegativeprice" : totalnegativeprice, "Balanceprice" : balanceprice } }
   ); 
    count++;  
    if (count == batch) { 
        bulk.execute(); 
        bulk = db.getCollection('summary').initializeUnorderedBulkOp(); 
        count = 0;
    } 
});

if (count > 0) { 
      bulk.execute(); 
 }
```

Comment: its not working in cmd(im using mlb and i connected through cmd)

Comment: I was using incorrect collection name. Fixed it in the answer. Try again and see if it works. If it doesn't not please provide the  error you get  with updated code. Note I'm grouping on user id instead of mobile number. Please add more details. Please make sure you use numeric values in both collection.

Comment: its working but userid i am getting 2.0. {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58f750889a8a92e6286b91af"),
    "user_id" : 2.0,
    "Totalpositiveprice" : 1000.0,
    "Totalnegativeprice" : 0.0,
    "Balanceprice" : 1000.0
}

Comment: The source collection  `userpricing`  has `user_id` with value 2.0(float). So that is what you see in `summary` collection. Is that not what you expect ?

Comment: user_id  should get 1 and 2  i don want 2.0 like

Comment: How did you create documents in item pricing collection ? Mongodb saves the numeric values as float when you don't specify type. Use NumberInt type when creating document.

Comment: i need your help sir

Comment: Sure. What is your query ?

Comment: can you come to chat sir?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `conditional sum` and export in another collection use `$out: collectionName`

can try it :

```
db.getCollection('userpricing').aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id:"$user_id", 
        user_id: {$first: "$user_id"}, 
        Totalpositiveprice:{$sum:{$cond:[{ '$gt': ['$price', 0]}, "$price", 0]}}, 
        Totalnegativeprice:{$sum:{$cond:[{ '$lt': ['$price', 0]}, "$price", 0]}},
        Balanceprice:{"$sum":"$price"}}
     },
     {$project: {_id:0, user_id:1, Totalpositiveprice:1, Totalnegativeprice:1, Balanceprice:1}},
     {$out: "summary"}
])
```

**N.B:** result exported in **summary** collection

Comment: please check my question and help me out

Comment: {
    "user_id": "1",
    "Totalpositiveprice": "5000.0",
    "Totalnegativeprice": "-1000",
    "Balanceprice": "4000.0"
}

Comment: can you please help me out @Shaishab Roy

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you want to do involves a complex query. See the below query. Let me explain it first.

1- first pipeline `$group` is obvious to you.

2- second pipeline `$lookup` is required to generate your desired result as you want that the current prices and the already summarized prices should be compiled into one document.

3- third stage is just unwinding the array `summary` we have looked up so that we will be able to compile the prices.

4- fourth `$project` stage is doing what you really want to do that is to say that it is compiling the summary document you will be able to understand it.

5- generating the summary collection.

```
db.getCollection('userpricing').aggregate([
     {$group:{
            _id:"$user_id",
            Totalpositiveprice:{$sum:{$cond:{if:{ $gt:["$price",0]}, then: "$price", else: 0}}},
            Totalnegativeprice:{$sum:{$cond:{if:{ $lt:["$price",0]}, then: "$price", else: 0}}},
            Balanceprice:{"$sum":"$price"}
     }},
     {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "summary",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "user_id",
          as: "summary"
        }
     },
     {$unwind:{path:"$summary", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}},
     {$project:{
         _id:0,
         user_id:"$_id",
         Balanceprice:{$add:["$Balanceprice", {$cond:{if:{ $eq:["$summary",undefined]}, then: 0, else: "$summary.Balanceprice"}}]},
         Totalnegativeprice:{$add:["$Totalnegativeprice", {$cond:{if:{ $eq:["$summary",undefined]}, then: 0, else: "$summary.Totalnegativeprice"}}]},
         Totalpositiveprice:{$add:["$Totalpositiveprice", {$cond:{if:{ $eq:["$summary",undefined]}, then: 0, else: "$summary.Totalpositiveprice"}}]}
     }},
   {$out:"summary"}  
])
```

Comment: @its me, if this solves your problem then, you should comment here that's how I will be assured that I have given right solution.

Comment: The only problem with $out is that it wipes out the whole collection and replaces it with your current aggregation. There is no way to append to an existing collection.

Answer (score -1):

As from other answers, the problem with `$out` is that it will replace the `summary` collection if one exists and you may not want that. You can use a little JavaScript for that.

```
var cursor = db.userpricing.aggregate([
  {
    $group : {
      _id : "$user_id",
      Totalpositiveprice : {
        $sum : {
          $cond : {
            if: { $gte : ["$price" , 0]},
            then : "$price",
            else : 0
          }
        }
      },
      Totalnegativeprice : {
        $sum : {
          $cond : {
            if: {$lte : ["$price" , 0]},
            then : "$price",
            else : 0
          }
        }
      },
      Balanceprice : {$sum : "$price"}
    }
  },
  {
    $project : {
      _id : 0,
      user_id : "$_id",
      Totalpositiveprice : 1,
      Totalnegativeprice : 1,
      Balanceprice : 1
    }
  }
]);

while(cursor.hasNext()) {
  var elem = cursor.next();
  db.summary.update(
    {user_id : elem.user_id},
    elem,
    {upsert : true}
  );
}



> db.summary.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58564bb71e2cb47f2ddcf1b4"), "Totalpositiveprice" : 10000, "Totalnegativeprice" : 0, "Balanceprice" : 10000, "user_id" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58564bb71e2cb47f2ddcf1b5"), "Totalpositiveprice" : 20000, "Totalnegativeprice" : -10000, "Balanceprice" : 10000, "user_id" : 1 }
```

Comment: its working but for user id 1 i should get like this {
    "user_id": "1",
    "Totalpositiveprice": "5000.0",
    "Totalnegativeprice": "-1000",
    "Balanceprice": "4000.0"
}

Comment: @itsme: `user_id` and the values in your `userpricing` collection are integers / numbers. However in your summary collection, they are strings. If thats the actual scenario in your database, then you'll have to do conversions.