# MongoDB Update from Aggregate

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am extremely new to Mongo and need some up creating an update statement. I have two different collections. I need to update the one collection's values with the results from my aggregate query where the id's match.

Here is my aggregate query that gives me the id for the other collection and the value I need to set it to:

```
db.ResultsCollection.aggregate(
    {$group:{_id:"$SystemId", "maxValue": {$max:"$LastModified"}}}
);
```

How do I loop through the other collection with this data and update where the _id matches the SystemId from my aggreagate?

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
db.ResultsCollection.aggregate(
    {$group:{_id:"$SystemId", "maxValue": {$max:"$LastModified"}}}
).forEach(function(     
    db.CollectionToUpdate.updateOne(
      { _id : doc._id },
      { $set: {UpdateDate: doc.maxValue } },
      { upsert: false }
   );   
});
```

My updated code does not generate a syntax error, but does not update the results when I refresh.

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074339/how-can-i-calculate-price-positive-and-negative-price-using-mongodb-or-robomongo/43477056#43477056

Comment: @Veeram: I added a version of this code, but it isn't working. Any insights?