# mongodb write aggregation output to a collection without wiping out previous data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a `user` collection and a `job` collection. whenever a new job is inserted, I'm running an aggregate pipeline query which outputs a list of documents which I require for my future work.

with the `$out` operator I can write to let's say `match` collection. Now whenever new job is inserted and the query is running again, the new outputs wipes out all the previous data of the `match` collection. which I don't want but working as per [documented](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#replace-existing-collection) in MongoDB.

To make my data persistent, I can call `toArray()` in my app and then write into a new collection. But that won't scale for 10,000 to 1M documents as far as I understand. My question is, can I (possible?) solve this specific problem without putting much load on the memory?
 Anything like bulkInsert with the cursor? a bit delayed computation won't hurt much though

Here's structure of my pipeline.

```
// ... previous stages
const stage7 = {
  $out: 'match'
}
....
collection.aggregate(
  [stage1, stage2, stage3, stage4, stage5, stage6, stage7],
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('agg failed error ', err)
      throw new Error('aggregation failed to write in match db', err)
    }
    console.log('write to db aggregation done', result)
  }
)
```

Comment: Map-Reduce can be an option, but i'm more interested with aggregation framework based approach

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41074339/2683814) helps.

Comment: I guess it is going put the same load on my memory as it'd put for `toArray`. I want to put pressure on my mongodb not the application +Veeram

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. Bulk processing is done on server side. The aggregation outputs a cursor and for each to accumulate the updates/upserts into bulk updates and submit to mongodb.

Comment: Aah okay. maybe my grammatical tone was not quite clear. now makes sense. thank you

Comment: There is currently an open feature request to append during `$out`, see [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12280)

Answer (score 1):

You can use $merge as it's now available from MongoDB 4.2 and onwards.

Link of documentation:[$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/)

> Ex:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $merge: {
            into: "your_output_collection",
            on: [
                "_id"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```